# How to assess the relative abundance of specific taxa in phyloseq?

Tags: r, subset, phyloseq

I have my relative abundance for all samples (X). I have also taken the subset_taxa of that overall for the specific genera (Y). How do I now go about measuring the relative abundance of Y in X?

`ps<-phyloseq(ASV,TAX,mapfile,tree)`
`relabun<-transform_sample_counts(ps,function(x) x / sum(x))`
`ps_genusP <- subset_taxa(ps, Genus == "D_5__Flavisolibacter" | Genus == "D_5__Halomonas"| Genus == "D_5__Thiobacillus"| Genus == "D_5__Sphingomonas"| Genus == "D_5__Bacillus" | Genus == "D_5__uncultured Acidobacterium sp." | Genus == "D_5__Bradyrhizobium"| Genus == "D_5__Ohtaekwangia"| Genus =="D_5__Steroidobacter")`

How do I find the relative abundance of ps_genusP genera in the ps (total community)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can see you created your new phyloseq object (`ps_genusP`) from `ps` instead of your `relabun`. In this way, `ps_genusP` shows the raw count data instead of relative abundances.
Moreover, you might want to **agglomerate** your data at genus level.

As for your question, my favorite way is to transform my phyloseq object into a dataframe and then use the tidyverse functions to access whatever information I need.

So, in your shoes, I would do:

```
library(phyloseq)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

relabun.ps <- transform_sample_counts(ps,function(x) x / sum(x))
ps_genus <- tax_glom(relabun.ps, taxrank = "Genus", NArm = FALSE)
ps_genusP <- subset_taxa(ps_genus, Genus %in% c("D_5__Flavisolibacter", "D_5__Halomonas",
                                                "D_5__Thiobacillus", "D_5__Sphingomonas",
                                                "D_5__Bacillus", "D_5__uncultured Acidobacterium sp.", 
                                                "D_5__Bradyrhizobium", "D_5__Ohtaekwangia", 
                                                "D_5__Steroidobacter")
```

```
genus.df <- psmelt(ps_genusP)
head(genus.df)
names(myphyla.df)  # to choose factors you want to use to navigate

MySummary <- genus.df %>%
  group_by(Factor1, Factor2, Genus) %>%
  summarize(mean_abund = mean(Abundance, na.rm=TRUE)) 
head(MySummary)
```

Now you will have a dataframe that looks like this:

*A tibble: 6 x 6
Groups:   Factor1, Factor2

Factor1  Factor2  Genus  mymean
          
1 Level1 LevelA Genus1     0.107
2 Level1 LevelA Genus2     8.83
3 Level1 LevelB Genus1     0.0101
4 Level1 LevelB Genus2     17.2
5 Level2 LevelA Genus1     0.533
6 Level2 LevelA Genus2     0.00121*

And that you can use to extract information:

```
MySummary[MySummary$Genus == "Genus1" & MySummary$Factor1 == "Level1" , ]
```

I hope this can be helpful. Cheers